# Mysql dependencies in securesocial

Tags: mysql, playframework, playframework-2.1, securesocial

I am trying to use mysql 5.5.27 database into securesocial sbt-version 0.12.2 with play 2.1.0. What changes should I include into the variable appdependencies in Build.scala to include the mysql?

Answer (score 1):

Add a line in the form:

`"mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.18" // mySQL driver`

in your `appDependencies` variable Seq.

Hope this helps.